# Error al compilar con la versión 6.0.0 de org.springframework:spring-web: cannot access org.springframework.http.HttpMethod

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

Estoy teniendo problemas al compilar mi proyecto con la versión 6.0.0 de org.springframework:spring-web. El error que estoy recibiendo es "cannot access org.springframework.http.HttpMethod". He revisado mi código y estoy seguro de que no hay errores de sintaxis ni de referencia.

He intentado buscar soluciones en línea, pero no he encontrado nada relevante. ¿Alguien ha experimentado este error antes o tiene alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Aquí está mi dependencia en el archivo pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version> <!-- Antigua: 5.1.10.RELEASE -->
</dependency>
```

Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es tu versión de Java?

Comment: openjdk:8u162-jre-slim y tenemos que quedarnos en la 8, no quieren subir de versión por temas de compatibilidad de código

Comment: Pues está todo dicho, si no pasas a Java 17+ no podrás usar la versión 6. Lee la [noticia de lanzamiento](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga) donde dice: *Como una revisión importante del núcleo central, Spring Framework 6.0 viene con una línea de base de **Java 17+** y un cambio a Jakarta EE 9+ (en el espacio de nombres de jakarta), con un enfoque en las API de Jakarta EE 10 lanzadas recientemente, como Servlet 6.0 y APP 3.1.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La versión 6 de SpringFramework no funciona en versiones de Java inferior a la 17.

Está claramente explicado en la [noticia de lanzamiento](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga):

> As a major revision of the core framework, Spring Framework 6.0 comes
> with a Java 17+ baseline and a move to Jakarta EE 9+ (in the `jakarta`
> namespace), with a focus on the recently released Jakarta EE 10 APIs
> such as Servlet 6.0 and JPA 3.1. This provides access to the latest
> web containers such as Tomcat 10.1 and the latest persistence
> providers such as Hibernate ORM 6.1. Don't be stuck on Java EE 8, make
> the leap to the `jakarta` namespace, ideally straight to the Jakarta
> EE 10 level! The upcoming Spring Boot 3.0.0 release includes
> corresponding managed dependencies for you.

---

> Como una revisión importante del núcleo central, Spring Framework 6.0
> viene con una línea de base de Java 17+ y un cambio a Jakarta EE 9+
> (en el espacio de nombres de `jakarta`), con un enfoque en las API de
> Jakarta EE 10 lanzadas recientemente, como Servlet 6.0 y APP 3.1. Esto
> brinda acceso a los contenedores web más recientes, como Tomcat 10.1,
> y los proveedores de persistencia más recientes, como Hibernate ORM
> 6.1. No se quede atascado en Java EE 8, dé el salto al espacio de nombres `jakarta`, idealmente directo al nivel Jakarta EE 10. La
> próxima versión de Spring Boot 3.0.0 incluye las dependencias
> administradas correspondientes para usted.

Y también está claramente indicado en la Wiki del proyecto en [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#supported-versions):

**Supported Versions**

> - `6.0.x` is the main production line as of November 2022. This new generation of the framework comes with a JDK 17 and Jakarta EE 9
>   baseline.
> - `5.3.x` is the final feature branch of the 5th generation, with long-term support provided on JDK 8, JDK 11, JDK 17 and the Java EE 8
>   level.
> - `4.3.x` reached its official EOL (end-of-life) on December 31st, 2020. No further maintenance and security patches are planned in that line.
> - `3.2.x` reached its official EOL (end-of-life) on December 31st, 2016. No further maintenance and security patches are planned in that line.
>
> At this point, we recommend upgrading to the latest Spring
> Framework `6.0.x` / `5.3.x` release from Maven Central when possible.

---

**Versiones compatibles**

> - `6.0.x` es la línea de producción principal a partir de noviembre de 2022. Esta nueva generación del núcleo viene con una línea de base JDK 17 y Jakarta EE 9.
> - `5.3.x` es la última rama de características de la quinta generación, con soporte a largo plazo proporcionado en JDK 8, JDK 11,
>   JDK 17 y el nivel Java EE 8.
> - `4.3.x` alcanzó su EOL (end-of-life) oficial el 31 de diciembre de 2020. No se planean más parches de mantenimiento y seguridad en esa línea.
> - `3.2.x` alcanzó su EOL (end-of-life) oficial el 31 de diciembre de 2016. No se planean más parches de mantenimiento y seguridad en esa línea.
>
> En este punto, recomendamos actualizar a la última versión de Spring
> Framework `6.0.x` / `5.3.x` desde Maven Central cuando sea posible.

Por tanto, si estás en Java 8 y quieres usar SpringFramework 6+ tendrás que actualizar tu JDK de Java hasta al menos la versión 17 y si eso no es posible ahora por problemas de compatibilidad, no te queda otra que seguir con la versión `5.3` al menos (presta atención al último párrafo).